# Is the every open set in a product space contains an open set with compact boundry?

Tags: general-topology

Let N be an open set of YxZ. Is there exist an open set W in YxZ with compact boundry such that W is a subset of N?

Comment: Yes, take $W$ to be empty.

Comment: W should be non-empty!

Answer (score 1):

Not in general, no. For example, let $Y$ be an infinite set with the [particular point topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology), and $Z$ be a one-point space. Then $N=\{(p,*)\}$ (where $p$ is the particular point of $Y$ and $*$ is the only point of $Z$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Is the your answer satisfies in a Hausdorff space?

Comment: If you mean to ask whether my example is Hausdorff, it isn't. If you mean to ask whether there's a Hausdorff example, I don't know. I expect so, though.